# Converter "-12.0000"(string) para -12.0000(double). É possível?

Tags: c#

É possível converter `"-12.0000"`(string) para `-12.0000`(double) ?

Segue código:

```
var valor = "-12.0000";
var result = Convert.ToDouble(valor, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //-12 <--- perde zeros
```

Ou se preferir .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RnFB1f

Comment: Imagino que vá usar de outra forma, afinal neste código a conversão não é necessária a não ser para demonstração. Dependo de como for usar precisa ser bem diferente disto.

Comment: @Maniero É possível converter `"-12.0000"`(string) para  `-12.0000`(double) sem perder os "0000". ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Double é um tipo de dado que guarda valores, não formatação para exibição, ou seja, `12.00000000000000` é a mesma coisa que `12` apenas, os zeros são redundantes, eles por si só não são um valor e não são considerados. Isto que você quer pode ser alcançado com o ToString("0.0000"). Exemplo: `result.ToString("0.0000")` onde a variável result é double.

Comment: @MurariAlex é isso que o MurariAlex disse. Número segue regras matemáticas, texto é apenas desenho dos números que você monta como achar melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Você terá de passar o cultura para não perder os 0, ficará assim:

```
double longitude = double.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

O aconselhavel é sempre utilizar double para latitude e longitude.

Comment: Continua perdendo os "0".

Comment: Veja aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RnFB1f